# About Farm Chicken

Tags: chicken, food-science

For two years, I've been eating chicken grown up in farms. They don't taste like village chicken (chickens raised in villages here eating natural food). Why not? Are there any differences besides flavor?

Comment: where are you from, and where was your village? Chicken is different all around the world, just like most other foods. Tough (firm?) chicken is usually a sign of older chicken (typically egg laying hens), or badly cooked chicken

Comment: Me from India.Normally where some chickens are grown up by eating special food,care, this place is called firm.

Comment: Sorry, what is your question? If you are asking whether farm chickens are healthy, we must close the question, as healthy diet is offtopic per [faq].

Comment: I think that the OP is referring to 'battery chickens'.

Comment: I'm definitely seeing the phrase "chicken firm" on google but I'm having trouble pinning down a definition. The question definitely seems to be about differences between crate-raised chicken and free-range local chicken, however, and not about the texture of the meat.

Comment: Tahmina, I've edited your question to remove all mention of health, which is off-topic. I'm still not completely confident what you mean by "grown up in firm", so I left that alone. Please feel free to edit the question further to clarify that or anything else. (I'm happy to edit the English again, so don't worry too much about that, just try to explain clearly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the food industry, animals are grown with a food supply that maximizes their weight to time ratio, so that they weight the most in the least amount of time.

These animals are young and are unlikely to have produced any real notable flavor by the time they are on market.

Going out on a limb, "village" chicken is like when someone has had this chicken for a few years, such as for laying eggs, and is retiring the bird. If so, this animal has not only probably been eating a different diet ( and thus having a different or stronger flavor ), but is also likely to be older, giving it time to build up a flavor.

Comment: here village chicken is which chicken are not grown up in firm,eat natural  food

Comment: Home chicken growers indeed eat their old egglayers, but these are nowhere near sufficient for the meat needs of a family. It is normal for people living in villages to hatch many chickens specifically as meat animals and to slaughter them early, retaining only a few egg layers each year.